# Getting all values in pdf from data table

Tags: datatables

I am using jquery datatable and listing only the required values in each pagination. However when I am trying to export it to pdf using pdf option, I can only export data present in the datatable. Is there any way I can get all values

Comment: Do you want to export an additional data with default `DataTable` export in PDF format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [DataTable Documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier#Server-side-processing) there is no way to export all rows when you are using server side processing.

> **Server-side processing**
>
> Special note on server-side processing: When using DataTables in
>   server-side processing mode (serverSide) the selector-modifier has
>   very little effect on the rows selected since all processing
>   (ordering, search etc) is performed at the server. Therefore, the only
>   rows that exist on the client-side are those shown in the table at any
>   one time, and the selector can only select those rows which are on the
>   current page.

*Well the only way is to add the `ALL` parameter to length menu and select it before exporting.*

*This way `DataTable` will export all the rows as those are shown on the UI.*

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "/your_ajax_url/",
    lengthMenu: [[10, 100, -1], [10, 100, "All"]],
    .....
```

Well if you want some custom message with `DataTable` then it provides the functionality to export table with some custom message to identify the result better.

The message is

> message :
>   Optional description message that will be shown above the table in the created PDF.

**DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/n6gsh0j1/1/**

The syntax for adding message to table is like below

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                message: 'PDF created by Prakash with Buttons for DataTables.'
            }
        ]
});
```

> If you want to modify(I mean styling) the exported PDF have a look at http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted

They have provided some cool stuff for the exported PDF.

> I you want to explore the other options available with PDF export have a look at
>   https://datatables.net/reference/button/pdf

Comment: I am displaying the data in data-table through ajax. I only show the 10 result in the first pagination and on clicking second pagination ajax is called and another 10 result is shown. so when I export only 10 result will be shown in the PDF. I want all results.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, got an idea from it to customise my datatable